# Can't connect camera ip with Emgu

Tags: c#, emgucv

I have problem when connect IP of camera like `http://192.168.1.101`.

I've seen in emgu document the url must like:

```
Capture cap = new Capture("rtsp://username:password@[IP Address]/mpeg4/media.amp");
```

But my camera use in LAN.

How to connect camera with IP `http://`? If it impossible, I hope anybody can say any solution for that.

Like convert `http:// protocol` to `rtsp:// protocol`.

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26527520/stream-from-ip-cam-c-sharp

Comment: This not work for me. I want connect with Emgu in LAN - Local Area Network.

I'm change your link:

`"http://192.168.1.101:8080/videostream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=admin";`

Comment: I use Geovison camera and that link to connect.

But when connect, it bugs.
http://www.camera-sdk.com/p_174-how-to-connect-to-your-geovision-ip-camera-onvif.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I would suggest is make sure you are using Emgu CV V3 not any of the lower versions.

If you are using it in lan it will still have an IP address and an RTSP port,

All I type in for my camera is:

```
Capture cap = new Capture("rtsp://username:password@cameraIP:RtspPort");
cap.ImageGrabbed += ProcessFrame;
cap.Start();
```

Then my ProcessFrame looks like this:

```
private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Mat image = new Mat();
        _capture.Retrieve(image);
        imageBox1.BackgroundImage = image.Bitmap;

    }
```

Comment: I use lastest Emgu CV v3. But I can

Comment: Did you try what I said about? You are going to have to make sure that your camera actually has an rtsp stream by going into it's settings and going to ports and seeing if there is an option for rtsp port or not.

Comment: *EDIT*
Download VLC Player then do the following:

Click on "Media" - "Open Network Stream" try typing in your rtsp stream in there, then beside the "Stream" button you will see a drop down arrow. Click the arrow and change it to "Play". 

VLC is great for streaming and if that can't find your camera then there is something wrong with your syntax for sure