# Importing live camera feed into unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, raspberry-pi, video-streaming, streaming

I have a problem that i couldn't figure out using the internet. I have a raspberry camera that streams on a web ip, the script for streaming is a python script, "http://192.168.0.94:8000/index.html" in my case, and i want to import the stream into a unity application. Anyone did that before? How it should be done? Like, when i press play in unity, i want to be able to see the images that camera record in a gamaobject of the application! Thank you for your time!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

public class WebStreams : MonoBehaviour
{

    public MeshRenderer frame;    //Mesh for displaying video

    private string sourceURL = "http://192.168.0.94:8000/index.html";
    private Texture2D texture;
    private Stream stream;

    public void GetVideo()
    {
        texture = new Texture2D(2, 2);
        // create HTTP request
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sourceURL);
        //Optional (if authorization is Digest)
        ///req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        // get response
        WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
        // get response stream
        stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
        StartCoroutine(GetFrame());
    }

    IEnumerator GetFrame()
    {
        Byte[] JpegData = new Byte[65536];

        while (true)
        {
            int bytesToRead = FindLength(stream);
            print(bytesToRead);
            if (bytesToRead == -1)
            {
                print("End of stream");
                yield break;
            }

            int leftToRead = bytesToRead;

            while (leftToRead > 0)
            {
                leftToRead -= stream.Read(JpegData, bytesToRead - leftToRead, leftToRead);
                yield return null;
            }

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(JpegData, 0, bytesToRead, false, true);

            texture.LoadImage(ms.GetBuffer());
            frame.material.mainTexture = texture;
            stream.ReadByte(); // CR after bytes
            stream.ReadByte(); // LF after bytes
        }
    }

    int FindLength(Stream stream)
    {
        int b;
        string line = "";
        int result = -1;
        bool atEOL = false;

        while ((b = stream.ReadByte()) != -1)
        {
            if (b == 10) continue; // ignore LF char
            if (b == 13)
            { // CR
                if (atEOL)
                {  // two blank lines means end of header
                    stream.ReadByte(); // eat last LF
                    return result;
                }
                if (line.StartsWith("Content-Length:"))
                {
                    result = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring("Content-Length:".Length).Trim());
                }
                else
                {
                    line = "";
                }
                atEOL = true;
            }
            else
            {
                atEOL = false;
                line += (char)b;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Right now it is unclear what software do you use for the streaming. I would suggest to incorporate this extra information into your question (i.e. edit your post). I would suggest you to figure out standard of streaming which do you use and then search for combination of standard (probably rtsp) + unity3d

Comment: well 192.168.x.x is not routable on the internet so you wont be able to see it off your local network with that address you would need to make it accessible from the internet and use an internet IP

Comment: @BugFinder i know, i am on my local network now. This is a code i found and i try to insert it on the main camera and as frame a cube, but nothing happens sadly.

Comment: possibly the index is returning html not a video stream...

Comment: Can you try utilize the Image.FromStream command, [as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26527520/stream-from-ip-cam-c-sharp)?

Comment: FMETP STREAM could you an alternative for Live Streaming purpose.

Comment: Im figureing the same thing out now, I would imagine that you would need to utilize specialized code to read the raw pixel data from the rasberry pi host and draw it into a raw image each frame in inity.